# Relationship between did and has done

Tags: adjectives

He did the job. 
He has done the job. 
Are the two same? If so which is the adjective?

Answer (score 2):

A quick answer: neither of these are adjectives; *did* is the preterite (past simple) tense of *to do* while *has done* is the past perfect of *to do*.

The difference between these tenses is highlighted [here](http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/past-simple-or-past-perfect):

> These two tenses are both used to talk about things that happened in the past. However we use past perfect to talk about something that happened before another action in the past, which is usually expressed by the past simple.
>
> For example:
>   *"**I had already eaten** my dinner when he called."*
>
> In other words, first I ate my dinner, then he called. 
>   The past perfect is often used with *already*, *yet*, *just* and *even*.

Comment: Is there a word eaten?

Comment: Yes, it's the past participle of eat.